# Error in executing query in Phalcon but query works on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have following table structure

```
        headline
        is_user_article
        is_approved
        updated_date
        created_date
```

I want to sort record in such a way that

1. if is_approved = 0, sort by  is_user_article DESC, updated_date DESC, created_date DESC
2. if is_approved = 1, sort by  updated_date DESC, created_date DESC

That means I want those articles at first which are user submitted(is_user_article=1)  and is not approved (is_approved=0), then rest of the records ordered by updated date and created date.

I have following query

```
<?php
        $phql = "SELECT headline, is_user_article, created_date, updated_date, is_approved 
            FROM NewsRoom\Articles\Models\Articles ORDER BY
            CASE is_approved WHEN 0 THEN is_user_article END DESC,
            CASE WHEN is_approved = 1 THEN updated_date END DESC,
            updated_date DESC,
            created_date DESC";

        $articles = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
?>
```

**PROBLEM**

The query doesnot work when I executed using `Phalcon's modelManager`. I get  `"Syntax error, unexpected token WHEN near is_approved=1"`

However, if I execute this query in phpMyadmin replacing `NewsRoom\Articles\Models\Articles` with actual table name `tbl_articles`, it works flawlessly.

Can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL from

```
 CASE WHEN is_approved = 1 THEN updated_date END DESC,
```

to

```
 CASE is_approved WHEN 1 THEN updated_date END DESC,
```